# sas variable not found in simulating binomial distribution

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I was wondering how to cure the variable not found problem in creating a binomial distribution?

```
DATA additional (KEEP=X);
  DO REPEAT = 1 TO 1000;
    CALL STREAMINIT(1234);

    DO I=1 TO 1000;
      X=RAND("BINOMIAL",0.6,10); /*NUMBER OF WINS IN TEN TOSSES*/
    END;

    IF X GE 5 THEN WINNER + 1;
    ELSE LOSER + 1;
    OUTPUT;
  END;
RUN;
PROC PRINT DATA=additional;
  VAR WINNER LOSER;
RUN;
```

I am creating a binomial random variable which if x is great than 5 then counts one for the winner, if less than 5 then counts one for the loser, the question is asking to found how many time are winners and how many times are losers. I kept on getting variable not found error. Am i doing something wrong with generating the binomial distribution.

/*further editing*/ this is the problem I am given.

You are given $10. Let the variable money = 10.
You play a game 10 times. The probability that you win a game is 0.4,
and the probability that you lose a game is 0.6.
If you win a game, you win $1. If you lose a game, you lose $1. So if
you win the first game, money becomes 11. But if you lose the first
game, money becomes 9.
After you have played the game 10 times, money is the amount that you
go home with. If you end up with at least $10, call yourself a winner.
Otherwise, call yourself a loser. Define the variable result as winner
or loser.

(a) Write a data step to generate random numbers and simulate your
result 1000 times. So that I can easily check your outputs, use
1234 as your seed for the random number generator. (You do not
need to show me the 1000 results.)

(b) Write a proc step to show how many times you are a winner, and
how many times you are a loser.

Comment: Since you told the first data step that it should only keep the variable X you cannot tell PROC PRINT to print the variables WINNER and LOSER as they were not written to the dataset.

Comment: Are you expecting to output 1,000 observations or 1,000,000? Your current looping will generate 1,000 values of X and ignore the first 999 of them.

Comment: thank you Tom! yes I am trying to get an output of 1000 observation.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understand that you want to do with simulation. From your codes, you just keep 1000 records, which are all kept at last loop because of your first loop end position; call streaminit should be first line; you only keep X, you could not get winner and loser variable.

I guess maybe you could try this.

```
DATA additional;
CALL STREAMINIT(1234);
DO REPEAT= 1 TO 1000;  *numbers of sample;
DO I=1 TO 100;         *size of sample;
X=RAND("BINOMIAL",0.6,10); /*NUMBER OF WINS IN TEN TOSSES*/
IF X GE 5 THEN results='WINNER';
ELSE results='LOSER';
OUTPUT;
END;
END;
RUN;

proc freq data=additional;
by repeat;
table results;
run;
```

Edit: It seems that you want to know final results, you could get it from above code by changing results as numeric variable. Here is modified codes, if win is +1, lose is -1.

```
DATA additional;
CALL STREAMINIT(1234);
DO REPEAT= 1 TO 100;  *numbers of sample;
DO I=1 TO 10;         *size of sample;
X=RAND("BINOMIAL",0.6,10); /*NUMBER OF WINS IN TEN TOSSES*/
IF X GE 5 THEN results+1;
ELSE results=results-1;
OUTPUT;
END;
results=0;
END;
RUN;


proc freq data=additional;
by repeat;
table results;
run;
```

Comment: thank you so much Shenglin!  sorry i was not specify the problem that was given and that caused some misunderstandings. I edited the problem. So I am trying to find the frequency of this random generating binomial distribution.